# Officejs Changing Footer font style makes it disappear

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In my code I am trying to change font style of footer. When I run the following code my Footer disappears.

```
function applyFontPreference(optionNo){
    Word.run(function (context) {
        const sections = context.document.sections;
        sections.load('body/font');
        return context.sync().then(function(){
            var footer = sections.items[0].getFooter("Primary")
            footer.font.name = "Arial";
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you declare Word?? I am stuck in that. I am getting an error: Word is not defined.

Comment: The "error :Word is not defined" appears when either the "Office.js" is not loaded OR you have not initialized the Officejs inside your javascript file.

Comment: I am using Typescript in an Angular app. Not sure how to initialize. Didn't get a proper documentation

Comment: How did you initialize in js?

Comment: Office.initialize = function (reason) {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the properties `font` and `name` haven't been loaded. I tested in Script Lab (using TypeScript) and the error I got with the code in the question was

> PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'name' is not available. Before
>   reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing
>   object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.

Putting in lines to load a sync for the property worked:

```
    footer.load('font/name');
    await context.sync();
```